# Use function with parameter in add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts') wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to figure out how to add a function with a parameter in add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');

```
function css_style($a){ 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'something'); 
    $style = 'background:#'.$a;
    wp_add_inline_style( 'something', $style );     

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','css_style');
```

The example is king of stupid because obviously it doesn't work. What I need is to pass function css_style to add_action. I tried adding css_style into another function and calling that function in add_action, but again it doesn't work.

Is there a solution? Thank you!

Comment: You would need to generate your styling inside that function instead of passing it in. There are ways around it but they'd be considered bad practice.

Comment: I tried various ways and iti doesn't work through add_action. The only way is to wrap everything with '<style>' and voila, it works.